# TYPO3 11 + Solr how to preselect a facet Option?

Tags: solr, typo3

I use TYPO3 11 with ex_solr 11.5.3 and I have a lot of facets. At one of my facets I want to preselect an specific option if the solr list is loaded.

I can't find any settings in the solr facet documentaion where I could to this.

Had anyone this problem and has a solution or Idea?

Thanks Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Raidri
There is no TypoScript setting and no UI possibilities on EXT:solr for this purpose.
On TYPO3 Slack the same question was asked recently, see: https://typo3.slack.com/archives/C02FF05Q4/p1687423195854459

TLDR: You must klick the facet-options together on FE and copy the Link, then you can place this Link on search page or as a target link for your preselected search page.